# add sql function to entity framework that returns entity object

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a sql function in a database that is mapped to an entity framework model.

When I add it my model, it returns a result which is of complex data type (usually named `functionName_Result`).

Is it possible to make such a function so that its return type is one of my model entities?

For example if I have a model-first entity framework model that contains A entity, can I make sql function in the database that returns A class instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your SQL table valued function so that it returns the data exactly matching your model classes. Usually you have `Table1` class in your model and `Table1` table in the database and the table valued function `FGetTable1Data` returns `SELECT * FROM Table1 ...` - the names of columns in SQL returned resultset must exactly match with the names and data types in your model.

If you have model-first see the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859577.aspx.

In the model-first approach you will have to do it in Visual Studio in the interactive model designer:

- Right-click the design surface and select **Model Browser**
- In **Model Browser**, select **Function Imports**, and then double-click the your function
- In the **Edit Function Import** dialog box, select **Entities** and choose the entity you want to be the return type of your table-valued function

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716672%28v=vs.100%29.aspx